# Spaces in file path and dirname(__File__)

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress / PHP related question.

I have a Wordpress plugin that uses `dirname(__File__)` to retrieve some .js files from a theme folder.

The theme folder has a space in the name ie: "My Theme".

`dirname(__File__)` appears to be ignoring the space and is trying to load /`MyTheme/script.js` and so the script is not found.

Any help to rectify this problem (without removing the space from the directory name) would be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Is the current PHP file one level above the theme directory?

Comment: Never use spaces in file, folder, or database names

Comment: And your observation is wrong. `dirname()` does not strip spaces by itself. Why would it? Look elsewhere for that bug.

Comment: did you mean the constant `__FILE__` in all caps, not `__File__`?

Comment: This is the function: `if(function_exists('register_field')) {
     register_field('acf_time_picker', dirname(__File__) . '/acf_time_picker/acf_time_picker.php');
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, as others have said, spaces in file paths are not good.  Second a WordPress plugin should never be tied to a specific theme.

If the plugin is theme specific, you should just include it in the theme's functions.php, that way you have easy access to everything in the theme

Comment: Ive removed the space from the directory path to be in line with best practice.